# How to make item appear if it is true

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I have a Database and the name of the Database is `People` and that database has a bool value called `Joined`, (the value is by default false) when I click on a button and make it true I want it to appear on another page.
Favourites.dart:

```
Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');

  Widget listItem({
    required Map People,
  }) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          color: Colors.blue,
          ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Center(
              child: Text(People['Name'],
                  )),
          Text(People['Place'], style: tyStyle),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(People['Date'], style: tyStyle),
          Text(
            People['Start Time'] + '  to  ' + People['End Time'],
            style: tyStyle,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  late bool joinedPeople;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPrefs(); // call the function here
  }

  Future<void> getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      joinedPeople = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Text(
                  'You Have Joined:',
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
                  query: dbRef,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                      Animation<double> animation, int index) {

                    Map People = snapshot.value as Map;
                    if (joinedPeople) {
                      return listItem(People: People);
                      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT IS RETURING EVERYTHING
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]));
  }
```

HomePage.dart:

```
void savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']);
      // print(People['Joined']);
    }
//
startActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 1 / 5,
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            icon: Icons.add,
            label: 'Join',
            onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
              setState(() {
                  //change value from false to true
                People['Joined'] = true;
                //then save it with setbool()
                savebool();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

`joinedPeople` is a bool that I have saved with Shared Preferences thus `getbool` is invoked so when joinedPeople gets the bool from People['Joined'] and it is true then it should display the ones you have joined, but right now the code is returning everything in the database. This is the problem...

What I have tried: I tried to use ChatGPT but it wants me to put every item's bool that is true into a string then I should also save that string with `SharedPreferences` and display the string, but this seems unnecessary && I also tried  `if (joinedPeople == true) {}` but it gives the same error

Comment: Show the function of saving the book value in SharedPreferences

Comment: I added the code which you asked for hopefully it makes more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that you should look out for in your logic.

You get the bool value of joinedPeople from shared Preferences, using the key `People['Joined']`. However you state that the value should be gotten from `People['Joined']`, which makes the shared preference redundant, unless you are using it elsewhere.

Solution 1 (Not recommended Personally): You need to set the value of the key in shared preferences first, and then retrieve it. Like so:

```
  Future<void> getPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']) // Second parameter is the value that you are setting.
      joinedPeople = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
    });
  }
```

Solution 2 (Recommended solution): Simply use your value that you get from your database in your method, and remove the shared Preferences completely.

```
if (People['Joined']) {
return listItem(People: People);
 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM IT IS RETURING EVERYTHING
} else {
  return Container();
}
```

You might also be using the entire object of people, and might need to use the index together with the snapshot.

Comment: The reason I use `if (joinedPeople) {}` is because I change the value of the boolean that is in the database and change it AND SAVE IT LOCALLY, so i use `joinedPeople` and not `People['Joined]']`

Comment: When I change the bool form false to true it changes everything to true how can I make each individual one true?

Comment: Is `People` an array, if so you need to set the specific item true that you want to set. But you also shouldn't use sharedPreference together with a list like that. 

Maybe you could just add the data structure of your `People`

Comment: could you explain in more depth please, I would like to try your method...oh and yes People is an array

Comment: If People is an array, then there are many `People['Joined']` booleans, thus you would have to check each and every one of those booleans and only populate the list items that match. Using your `AnimatedList`, you can use the itembuilder and the index, to select each index and build the ListItem for each item in People.

Comment: How would the code for that look like?

Comment: if (People[index]['Joined']) {
return listItem(People: People[index])
} else {
  return Container();
}